# Faux Concrete Wall

Tags: concrete, walls, cleaning

I really love the look of a faux concrete wall, and I would like to try it using joint compound and liquid cement colour. However, I'm a bit nervous to try it as I've never done anything like it before. How difficult is the clean-up? Is it difficult to get off the floor?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try outside on a piece of wood or somesuch, that practise makes so much difference to the real thing...

As for the floor, put down plastic sheet, taped down to cover the edges, and that will protect the surface.

Works well for any painting, decorating or other work. But if it is a carpet, then the first thing I usually do is to roll the carpet back out the way.

Comment: A sacrificial sheet of drywall is pretty cheap, assuming the wall to be treated is drywall. +1 for practice & plastic on the floor!

Comment: Practising outside is a great idea, thanks! Unfortunately, my carpet is permanent, and I'm worried that even if I stick my plastic sheet down it will shift a bit and I'll get my carpet messy... How do I make sure the sheet stays put?